# How to give individual value of check box column in where condition

Tags: php

[image]I have stored multiple values of check box in single datebase column.
how can i give individual value of check box column in where condition.

I want to select only Friday batch .I want sql query to select batch name having day Friday

Comment: show you saved data which is in DB how is it?

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this query $sql="SELECT * FROM batchinfo WHERE day='Friday' ";I am getting only one  result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `like` to get an exact string from column

```
SELECT * FROM `batchinfo` WHERE day like '%Friday%';
```